# how to upload a file in angularjs and send it to Database where path is given to store files in a folder?

Tags: angularjs

i have doubts about giving path in my SQL database to store uploaded files in folder.

I am new to the path giving concept.

Comment: You really need to give us more info.  What technology are you using for server side?  Have you tried anything?   If so, share your code.

Comment: i am a front end guy so i dont know much about server side language

Comment: If just doing the front end I can only assume that you are looking for suggestions on getting a file from the ui and making the appropriate $http call.  If that's the case, that issue has been addressed many times on here.  Search for "file upload"

Comment: ok thank you for suggestions